# How to add the sum in the listbox(visual basic) mix with other value, the value should get it price number

Tags: vb.net

[image: The layout]

[image: , dish with price]
from combobox to the dish i used **if statement** to display my dish in my dish area,

> from dish to the list i used:

```
Dim quantity As Integer

        quantity = txtQuantity.Text

        If lstDish.SelectedIndex > -1 Then
            Dim index1 As Integer

            index1 = lstDish.SelectedIndex

            Dim item1 As Object
            item1 = lstDish.SelectedItem

            lstList.Items.Add(item1 & " -->  " & quantity)

        End If
        txtQuantity.Text = 1
```

> The value display at list are will be in form Noodle -> 2
> What should i do to get the noodle value as 3.50 * my quantity 2 and add all my sum for the list

```
Dim Total As Integer
        Dim priceOfDish As String = 0
        Dim quantity As Integer
        Dim friesPrice, garlicBreadPrice, friedChickenWingPrice, springRollPrice As Double
        Dim chickenRicePrice, friedRicePrice, curryRicePrice, thaiChickenRice As Double
        Dim friedSeafoodNoodlePrice, chickenNoodlePrice, beefNoodlePrice, prawnNoodlePrice As Double

        Select Case priceOfDish
            Case Is = "Fries"
                friesPrice += 2.5
            Case Is = "Garlic Bread"
                garlicBreadPrice += 2.5
            Case Is = "Fried Chicken Wing"
                friedChickenWingPrice += 2.5
            Case Is = "Spring Roll"
                springRollPrice += 2.5
            Case Is = "Chicken Rice"
                chickenRicePrice += 4
            Case Is = "Fried Rice"
                friedRicePrice += 4
            Case Is = "Curry Rice"
                curryRicePrice += 4
            Case Is = "Thai Chicken Rice"
                thaiChickenRice += 4
            Case Is = "Fried Seafood Noodle"
                friedSeafoodNoodlePrice += 3.5
            Case Is = "Chicken Noodle"
                chickenNoodlePrice += 3.5
            Case Is = "Beef Noodle"
                beefNoodlePrice += 3.5
            Case Is = "Prawn Noodle"
                prawnNoodlePrice += 3.5
        End Select

        Total = priceOfDish * quantity
        txtTotal.Text = Total
    End Sub
```

> code for the total button

Comment: A more correct way to do this would be to create a CUSTOM CLASS that you add to the ListBox (instead of a String like you're doing).  Then you can override the `ToString()` method to control how it displays in the ListBox.  In your custom class, you can store the name, the price, and the quantity (all in separate fields with correct data types).  If the quantity is zero, then you'd display the name and the price.  If the quantity is not zero, then you'd display the name and the quantity.  You can add another method that calculates the cost based on the quantity and price fields.

Comment: Perhaps the following will help [GitHub repository](https://github.com/karenpayneoregon/EntityFrameworkSolutionStructureWindowsForms_VisualBasic/tree/master/CategoriesProducts)
![ScreenShot](https://github.com/karenpayneoregon/EntityFrameworkSolutionStructureWindowsForms_VisualBasic/blob/master/asserts/WindowScreenShot.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have only included the code to demonstrate one method of getting the total. As several others have mentioned, a Class is probably the best method but I don't think you have reached the use of classes in your course yet.

I have declared 2 form level variables to hold values that can be accessed from more than one method. They do not lose their values at the end of a Sub but maintain them as long as the Form is open. You will need to reset the `RunningTotal` button to 0 in your Clear button.

When the user selects a category the code resets the value of `CategoryCost` is set so it is ready if the user chooses to add an item form this category. It is reset every time a new category is chosen.

It is then a simple matter to calculate the cost and add it to the `RunningTotal` in the `AddButton`. Then it is displayed in the `txtTotal` by calling `.ToString` with the `"C2"` parameter which stands for Currency with 2 numbers after the decimal point.

```
Private RunningTotal As Decimal
Private CategoryCost As Decimal

Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim Category = ComboBox1.Text
    Select Case Category
        'Add your code to display the products in each category in the left hand list box
        Case "Snack"
            CategoryCost = 2.5D
        Case "Noodle"
            CategoryCost = 3.5D
        Case "Rice"
            CategoryCost = 4D
        Case Else
            CategoryCost = 0D
    End Select
End Sub

Private Sub AddButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AddButton.Click
    'Your code to display the selected item from the left list box in the right list box
    'can be entered here.
    RunningTotal += CDec(txtQuantity.Text) * CategoryCost
    'If you don't want to display a running total, put the following code in a total button
    txtTotal.Text = RunningTotal.ToString("C2")
End Sub
```

Comment: i use your solution, it help a lot but i still have some problem, the calculation  for the total is wrong, 1 snacks, 3 rice, 1 noodle should get 18 but i just get 16.50. add RunningTotal = 0 to the clear button is it correct? thanks for answer my question.

Comment: i have add the txtQuantity will equal to 1 after add the dish to the list is it effect to the final total?

Comment: oh, i just solved the problem, i.had put the txtQuantity = 1 above the calculation, thats the problem to get wrong answer, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can create a database for  store products and a table for products
By  this query

Put like this query on button click event

Declare @sum as integer=0

Select @sum=product_cost * “+val(textboxcount.text)+”  from product_table where product_name=“+listbox.selelcttext+”  <—-listbox selected

Comment: Good idea but probably beyond the scope of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a variable in the form and do your calculation in the Add Button (Not Total Button)

```
Public Class MyForm
    dim MyTotal as Double

    Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
         ' Do your stuff to move from dishes to the list
         MyTotal = MyTotal + (cdbl(txtQuantity.Text) * Price)
    End Sub
    Private Sub btnTotal_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnTotal.Click
         txt_Total.text = MyTotal.ToString("N2")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Where does the value of Price come from?